# Form validation problem in reactjs with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form

I'm trying to make form validation with react-hook-form. It works fine exept one propblem: it doesn't check input type. I want user to input only URL address, but this thing validate it as a simpte text. Where did I make a mistake?

```
function EditAvatarPopup({ isOpen, onClose, onUpdateAvatar, submitButtonName }) {

  const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [link, setLink] = useState('');

  function handleInput(e) {
    setLink(e.target.value)
  }

  function handleSubmitButton() {
    console.log(link)
    onUpdateAvatar({
      avatar: link
    });
  }

  return (
    <PopupWithForm 
      name="change-avatar"
      title="Update avatar" 
      submitName={ submitButtonName }
      isOpen={ isOpen }
      onClose={ onClose }
      onSubmit={ handleSubmit(() => handleSubmitButton() ) }
    >
      <label htmlFor="userAvatar" className="form__form-field">
        <input 
          id="userAvatar" 
          type="url"
          { ...register('userAvatar', { 
            required: "Enter URL link",
            value: link 
          }) 
          } 
          placeholder="url link"
          className="form__input" 
          onChange={ handleInput }
        />
        { errors.userAvatar && (<span className="form__error">{ errors.userAvatar.message }</span>) }
      </label>
    </PopupWithForm>
  );
}
```

It looks like type="url" doesn't work, but I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-js-forked-ml3zx?file=/src/App.js

I recommend to not overwrite `onChange` props, instead of using `const [link, setLink] = useState('');` you can use `const link = watch('userAvatar')`.

You can remove the `value` property, it's not necessary:

```
<input 
  id="userAvatar" 
  type="url"
  { ...register('userAvatar', { 
      required: "Enter URL link",
      value: link //⬅️ Remove that line
    }) 
  } 
  placeholder="url link"
  className="form__input" 
  onChange={ handleInput } //⬅️ Remove that line 
/>
```

[React Hook Form - Watch API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch)